# Can't get to paste in values only

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get to paste in values only.

My Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()    
    'Komanda rinkti duomenis
    a = Worksheets("Lapas1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("lapas1").Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("K5") Then
            Worksheets("lapas1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("lapas1").Activate
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Activate
    Range("K5").Activate
End Sub
```

Already tried:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()    
    Dim shtSrc as worksheet, shtDest as worksheet, i as long

    Set shtSrc = Worksheets("Lapas1")
    Set shtDest = Worksheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra")

    'Komanda rinkti duomenis
    For i = 2 To shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If shtSrc.Cells(i, 3).Value = shtDest.Range("K5").Value Then 'K5 sheet?

            shtDest.Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1, 0).Entirerow.value = _
                   shtSrc.rows(i).value

        End If
    Next

    shtDest.Activate
    shtDest.Range("K5").Activate
End Sub
```